# HTML Imports load order quirks?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, html-imports

Hey there!

I’m having a hard time understanding a specific behaviour with HTML Imports. I’m just swapping one line within the imports and get a totally different output.

So here is what I got…

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="./element-a.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./element-b.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./element-c.html">
</head>
<body>
    <element-a></element-a>
</body>
</html>
```

**element-a.html**

```html
<template>
    <element-b>
        <element-c>Hi!</element-c>
    </element-b>
</template>

<script>
console.log('registering a');

class ElementA extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        console.log('upgrading a');

        const $template = this.constructor.ownerDocument.querySelector('template');
        const $clone = $template.content.cloneNode(true);

        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild($clone);

        const $c = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('element-c');
        const isDefined = () => console[$c.say ? 'debug' : 'error'](`say() is ${$c.say ? '': 'un'}defined`)

        isDefined();

        const undefined = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(':not(:defined)');
        const promises = [...undefined].map(el => customElements.whenDefined(el.localName));

        console.log('undefined: ', undefined);

        Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            console.log('ready');
            isDefined();
        });
    }
}

ElementA.ownerDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

customElements.define('element-a', ElementA);
</script>
```

**element-b.html**

```html
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>

<script>
console.log('registering b');

class ElementB extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        console.log('upgrading b');

        const $template = this.constructor.ownerDocument.querySelector('template');
        const $clone = $template.content.cloneNode(true);

        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild($clone);
    }
}

ElementB.ownerDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

customElements.define('element-b', ElementB);
</script>
```

**element-c.html**

```html
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>

<script>
console.log('registering c');

class ElementC extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        console.log('upgrading c');

        const $template = this.constructor.ownerDocument.querySelector('template');
        const $clone = $template.content.cloneNode(true);

        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild($clone);
    }

    say(words) {
        console.log(words);
    }
}

ElementC.ownerDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

customElements.define('element-c', ElementC);
</script>
```

I also created a [pen](https://codepen.io/mzdr/project/editor/Zgazyp/). Now what’s confusing me: If I import `element-a` *first* I get this output:

> registering a
>   upgrading a
>   say() is undefined
>   undefined: (2) [element-b, element-c]
>   registering b
>   upgrading b
>   registering c
>   upgrading c
>   ready
>   say() is defined

But if I import it at last, I get a totally different output and order of *registering* and *upgrading*.

> registering b
>   registering c
>   registering a
>   upgrading a
>   upgrading b
>   upgrading c
>   say() is defined
>   undefined:  []
>   ready
>   say() is defined

Why is that? I kind of expect the last output to be the one that always happens. Has it something to do with the slotting/Shadow DOM?

Comment: From https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#upgrades: Note that upgrades only apply to elements in the document tree. An element that is not inserted into a document will stay un-upgraded. So in your 2nd example, they all register first because "A" is not in the document yet.

Comment: I see but I don’t get what the order of the import has to do with that? Especially since `element-a` is always in the document tree from the beginning in both cases.

Comment: `element-a` is in the document from the start, but `b` and `c` are not (until `a` gets registered). Those two get registered right away b/c you're loading their imports,. but they aren't upgraded until `a`'s import adds them to the document. Make sense?

Comment: Ah, that makes totally sense, Eric! It’s quite tricky to grasp especially when `script` tags after imports also come into play. Thanks for your great [html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) article!

Answer (score 1):

You should import element-a's dependencies inside element-a.html. HTMLImport imports and registers the component, that's why you get some undefined because register the component before you import other files (imports are async). Importing the dependencies inside the element the browser wait until all dependencies are ready before register the component.

You can read more about [Managing dependencies and sub-imports](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#depssubimports)

Comment: You should definitely try to manage deps inside the component's import that requires them. However, imports are not async by default and the browser doesn't wait until all imports are loaded before registering elements. I believe that's a polymer 1.0 thing.